# Linux file system supported special charactes

Tags: linux

I designed a Webpage with one text field which takes filename and i will take this as a file name and save in Linux system

i need to know which kind of combination of special characters(, . " ' : ; > < ? / | { } [ ] = + - _ * & ^ % $ # @ !) are allowed to name the file and which are not in Unix file system
.because i need to validate the file name entered by the user , will it support or not by Linux system

Eg: ".txt was not supporting but '.txt supporting

i study that Linux supports all but('/' and '\0')

how to know which will support and which doesn't(because there are lot of combinations with the above special characters)

Comment: A web search was probably easier: See [Filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) on Wikipedia.

Comment: All file systems which are intended and designed to be used on Linux or other Unixes should support all characters. FAT and NTFS, however, probably don't.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entierely on the file system. You should write code that works on any file systems.

To avoid in any case: `/` and `\` because the one will not work in UNIX, the other one will not work in Windows.

To avoid to make life easier: spaces of all kinds and sorts, i.e. (not just blank). To see why, try to create and delete a file named " \t\r\n", both in Windows and Unix. Just because spaces *are* allowed in file names doesn't mean using them is a good idea, some tools may not properly deal with them and it makes life easier in the command line (Remember, the a??hole who decided to name an important folder "Program Files" in Windows will surely burn in hell, because of the millions of curses devoted to him *every week* for his evil deed.)

To make life even easier for people: no shell special characters $&|, quoting characters and the like. Also, a directory whose name contains a ; or a : is impossible to use in PATH (or class paths) either on Windows or Unix.

Answer (score 0):

The file names can be any characters but / and \0 we cant use because, some time we can
use \0 also, you cannot see the file name while you put ls command, so that's why we should 
not use the \0 -NULL

cat > \space     Just give space after the the \
it will create the file when you put ls -l then you will find the created file.

Unix supports all the special character as file names.